# why following openmp code containing ordered "construct" does not execute?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, sleep

i am trying to execute following code ,
though i know that "syntactically" ordered construct should appear within the for loop,
but why the code gets stucked within ordered clause
i.e. execution should have given me a straight away "syntax error".

```
omp_set_num_threads(11);
#pragma omp parallel
{

// 1

 #pragma omp ordered
{
  printf("\n%d ",omp_get_thread_num());//this statement is not getting executed
}//ordered omp pragma

}//parallel omp pragma
```

the print statement at //1 was successful
i even tried to remove ompgetthreadnum() but still no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#pragma omp ordered` may only appear inside `#pragma omp for ordered` construct.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbt9k4s0.aspx)

Comment: Sergey ,then it should have given me syntax error
,; i  want to ask that why this code got stuck !

Comment: @PuneetS.Chauhan It got stuck because your openmp compiler did not realise that it is not in a `parallel for ordered` construct, but the openmp library you linked against it was waiting for the appropriate synchronisation signal.